# error occur while doing pygame project sudoku

Tags: python

```
        if valid(self.model, val, (row,col)) and solve(self.model):
            return True
        else:
            self.cubes[row][col].set(0)
            self.cubes[row][col].set_temp(0)
            self.update_model()
            return False
```

NameError: name 'valid' is not defined

Comment: Either `valid` isn't defined at all, or it's not defined by the time the interpreter reaches that line during execution. It's impossible to conclusively tell since you haven't shared all relevant parts of the code. Is `valid` an instance method? If so, it should be `self.valid(...)`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.